# Can't use expression "_ =>" in scala

Tags: scala

The following code isn't working:

```
val neighbors = ('a', List(1,2,3)) #:: ('b', List(2,3,4)) #:: ('c', List(3,4,5)) #:: Stream.empty
neighbors.count(_ => _._1 == 'a'))
```

However I can do:

```
neighbors.count(_._1 == 'a')
```

or:

```
neighbors.count(elem => elem._1 == 'a')
```

Both valid solutions.

**Question:** What is wrong with "_ =>"?

thank you very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is wrong with `_ =>`?

Nothing is *wrong* with it. It simply has a special meaning to the compiler. It means *"I want to **ignore** this value"*. It makes sense that if you want to ignore it, you want be able to apply any operations on it. It is similar to how placeholder syntax has a special meaning as well.

You can do:

```
neighbors.count(_._1 == 'a')
```

Because this is defined by the specification as placeholder syntax in anonymous functions, which expands to

```
neighbors.count(x => x._1 == 'a')
```

I can't find anything formal on this per the specification, but it does provide this example under [6.23 Anonymous Functions](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#anonymous-functions):

```
_ => 5                             // The function that ignores its argument
                                   // and always returns 5.
```

And I've also found [this post](http://scala-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/scala-Allowing-in-anonymous-functions-that-ignore-parameters-td1996674.html) on the old Scala language mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

The "_" symbol is used to make anonymous functions. Following your code:

```
neighbours.count(_._1 == 'a')
```

Is transformed to

```
neighbours.count(x => x._1 == 'a')
```

If there are two or more underscores, compilers tries to derive function with more arguments:

```
val numbers = List(1, 3, 4, 5, 6)
numbers.reduce(_ * _)
```

The code above is transformed to:

```
numbers.reduce((x1, x2) => x1 * x2)
```

It should be obvious now that there is no clear way to transform:

```
_ => _.1 == 'a'
```

Becouse it would need to produce function that takes two arguments.
One can imagine doing transformation like this:

```
x1 => x2 => x2._1 == 'a'
```

Scala compiler would even expand this definition but count function expects function with following signature:`T => Boolean`, not `T => T => Boolean`

For example the following compiles:

```
val test: Int => Int => Boolean = _ => _ == 3
```

Comment: *Becouse it would need to produce function that takes two arguments.* Why? The language itself could say that `_ => ` simply binds `_` to a fresh variable name, similar to how `_._1` already works.

Comment: I think that `_._1` simply produces a function `x => x._1`, similarly `_ => c` produces function ` x => c`, where c is an expression independent from x.